# file_exists(get_template_directory() - what's wrong?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got an fatal error: **syntax error, unexpected '")) {
' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)** in these lines:

```
if (file_exists(get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php")) {
    include_once get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php';
}
```

I tried to check it in IDE and in IDE **".php"))** it says 'expected semicolon'. Where is the problem? What I made wrong?

Comment: Thought about it: Your code does not make any sense after all. `get_template_directory()` will return a folder, so your basename will not complete with a result that makes any sense and your `file_exists` will therefore fail. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You got your string seperators mixed up. Either use single quotes for everything or double quotes for everything, but make sure you don't mix them up.

That's what happened in line 2 of your code sample:

```
# your code
include_once [...] . ".php';

# should be
include_once [...] . ".php";
```

Make sure to use an editor like Visual Studio Code or anything else that helps you find those things through code highlighting or a linter that will check your code while you type.

edit: See how even StackOverflows code highlighting gives you a hint, because lines 3 and 4 in my code block are marked as a string. That's a pretty good clue that something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if (file_exists(get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php")) {
    include_once get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "." . basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php';
}

Problem is in last line

basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php’

It should be

basename(get_template_directory()) . ".php";

Comment: Ok then try to make a static path first then make it dynamic. As there might be some problem with php fn configuration on your system

Comment: Also replace directory separator with string which you have defined somewhere. It might be the case that constant not getting its value